# How to use BIO_set_conn_ip with IP octets?

Tags: binary, openssl, ip, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying and use this function **BIO_set_conn_ip(b, ip)** of [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/)
which sets the IP address to ip using *binary form*, that is four bytes specifying the IP address in big-endian form.

Here is the [man](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/3ssl/BIO_set_conn_ip/) for Bio_set_conn_ip.

I wonder how to pass the ip to this function.

Let's say for an ip of this 100.100.100.100

If I was using hexadecimal I would pre-pone **0x** do this:

```
ip[0] = 0x64;
ip[1] = 0x64;
ip[2] = 0x64;
ip[3] = 0x64;
```

but what happens when I need to use a binary form?
I tried with passing its decimal value like this:

```
ip[0] = 1100100;
```

The compiler does not complain neither the linker, 
But this seems not to be working
because the successive function using **b** (*BIO_do_connect(b)*) returns a negative value.

The compiler I am using is GCC

Comment: The question is not clear unless you do some digging, adding a reference to a document such as a [man page like this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/BIO_set_conn_ip.3ssl.html) would help.

Comment: I edited my question but it is not really matter of the function but of the format to use.

Comment: have you tried the 0b format I suggested?

Comment: yes but still not working the program, please see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402771/openssl-bio-do-connect-returns-negative-value

Comment: This code has an [example](http://seclists.org/basics/2006/Sep/105) which suggests using `htonl` and an aliases unsigned long as a `char*` which should really be a `uint32_t`. I can not find any decent references.

Comment: Was the answer below helpful? From what I can tell it is not the answer but you have not commented so don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this depends on the compiler at hand.
The GCC allows you to use a binary constant extension, so you can write the number with **0b** prefix:

```
ip[0] = 0b01010101;
```

If your compiler doesn't have this feature, you can write your own function that would allow you to write a byte array representation of the binary and convert it to a hex value, so you can call it like:

```
ip[0] = toHex("0b01010101");
```

Where the toHex() takes a byte array and returns a numerical value. To find out how to write such a function, check out [this article](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/hexadecimal-binary-convert)

You can also use the [BOOST_BINARY](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#BOOST_BINARY) macro.